# How do I call a grand-parent's method, and skipping the parent in ruby

Tags: ruby, inheritance, super

How do I choose a particular a method call in the inheritance chain?

```
class A
  def boo; puts "A:Boo"; end
end

class B < A
  def boo; super; puts "B:Boo"; end
end

class C < B
  def boo; self.A.boo(???); puts "C:Boo"; end
end
```

Thus the output would be A:Boo, C:Boo

TIA,

-daniel

Comment: Instead of solving your Ruby problem like this, you may want to reconsider your design. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? A class inheriting from another class, but skipping parts of implemented parent methods, is very smelly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do

```
class C < B
  def boo
    A.instance_method(:boo).bind(self).call
    puts "C:Boo"
  end
end
```

However if you need this, that's usually an indicator that you should rethink your design. In particular if C needs A's implementation of `boo`, maybe B should not override it.

Comment: I would put it the other way around: if a C should not behave like a B, then C shouldn't be a subclass of B.

Comment: The class structure is A->B->C, but I wanted to avoid doing what B did and I overloaded, but I still needed to honor part of the API that A was providing which was a part of an plugin architecture.  Class B has 99% of the stuff I wanted to do though!

Comment: @Daniel it sounds like you're looking for modules to me :)